# WooCommerce API key - How to store safely

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

What harm can someone do when they have the `woocommerce-api key` that is normally stored in Wordpress itself? At the moment some endpoints in my front-end contains the WooCommerce API key.

Comment: How are you using the key? How are users using the end-point? What access rights does the key have? You define the access level of an API key.

Comment: I am using it in my for example `product_service.dart` file in my Flutter app. I need to use basic auth for example to retrieve the products. I know I can make a custom endpoint in PHP and call that one, but is that the best option?

Or is it better to indeed only give the user `read` rights. Since it is only needed when retrieving products.

Comment: Yeah, read rights only for a public API.

Comment: So setting in to `read only` rights is better than making a few custom PHP endpoints to retrieve the products)? They still have access to the API key if I just set it to `read only`

Comment: Doesn't matter if they have access if it's read only. As long as you are limiting it to products, you're fine.

Comment: Do you know how to limit it only to products? The key is only used when retrieving the products, but when they have the key, they can use postman and also call an endpoint to get all orders. And in the WooCommerce dashboard I only can set it to  `read` or `write` or `read and write`.

Comment: @disinfor Do you have idea?